# How to get selected items in spinner when It is inside custom adapter and selection of items are in activity

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a customer adapter where my layouts such as buttons edittext,textview,spinner are there.I'm getting all the value of the items in my Activity where there is an action for button of saving.Now I.m having problem on how to get the value inside my spinner because it gets a null value.here's my code

**MyAdapter.java**

```
package com.functions;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.example.senditem.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model>  {

 private final List<Model> list;


 String adapter;
    private final Activity context;
    private final int id;
    int listPosition;
    public MyAdapter(Activity context, List<Model> list, int id){
        super(context, R.layout.userproduct, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
        this.id = id;
    }


    class ViewHolder{
        protected TextView text;
        EditText quantity;
        protected TextView amount;
        TextView ext;
        Spinner uom;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        listPosition = position;
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.userproduct, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder(); 
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
            viewHolder.text.setFocusable(true);
            viewHolder.quantity = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inputQty);
            viewHolder.amount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inputAmt);
            viewHolder.uom = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inputUom);
            viewHolder.ext = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inputTamt);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.label, viewHolder.text);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.inputQty, viewHolder.quantity);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.inputAmt, viewHolder.amount);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.inputTamt, viewHolder.ext);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.inputUom, viewHolder.uom);
        }
        else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        SqliteHelper db = new SqliteHelper(context);
        viewHolder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        viewHolder.quantity.setId(position);
        viewHolder.amount.setText(String.valueOf(list.get(position).getAmt()));
        viewHolder.amount.setId(position);
        viewHolder.ext.setId(position);    
        viewHolder.uom.setId(position);
        viewHolder.text.setId(position);
        String data = db.getAllDetails(id, list.get(position).getitemId());
        String data2 = db.getExt(id,list.get(position).getitemId());
        if(data==null)
        {
            viewHolder.quantity.setText(list.get(position).quantity);       
        }
        else{
            viewHolder.quantity.setText(data);
        }
        if(data2==null)
        {
            viewHolder.ext.setText(String.valueOf(list.get(position).ext));
        }
        else{
            viewHolder.ext.setText(data2);
        }
        viewHolder.quantity.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                    if (!hasFocus){
                        final int position = v.getId();
                        final EditText Caption = (EditText) v;

                        list.get(position).quantity = Caption.getText().toString();              

                    }
                }
            });

        viewHolder.ext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus){
                        final int position = v.getId();
                        final TextView Caption = (TextView) v;    
                    list.get(position).ext = (float) Integer.parseInt((Caption.getText().toString()));

                }
            }
        });

        List<Model> uomlist = (List<Model>) db.selectUom(list.get(position).getitemId());
        List<String> myuom = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int j=0;j<uomlist.size();j++){
            myuom.add(uomlist.get(j).getUom());
        }


        ArrayAdapter<String> uomadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,myuom);
        uomadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        viewHolder.uom.setAdapter(uomadapter);

        return convertView;

    }





}
```

**UserItemDetailActivity**

```
package com.example.senditem;


import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import com.example.senditem.UserMainActivity.ViewHolder;
import com.functions.Model;
import com.functions.MyAdapter;
import com.functions.SqliteHelper;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class UserItemDetailActivity extends Activity {


ArrayAdapter<Model> adapter;
List<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();
ListView listView;

Button btnSave;
TextView textname;
EditText textqty;
TextView textamt;
Spinner uom;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.useritemdetail);


    Intent i=getIntent();
    final Bundle b = i.getExtras();
    final SqliteHelper db = new SqliteHelper(this);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.detail_list);
    btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);

    adapter = new MyAdapter(this, getModel(), Integer.parseInt(b.get("id").toString()) 

);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    uom = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.inputUom);


Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), b.get("itemname").toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    final String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());

    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(final View v) {
                listView.clearFocus();
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
                alert.setTitle("Save Details?");
                alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                        if(list.get(i).getQuantity()!=null)
                        {
                            float amt = list.get(i).getAmt();
                            int iqty = Integer.parseInt(list.get(i).getQuantity());
                            float tamt = amt * iqty;
                            list.get(i).setTamount(tamt);
                            list.get(i).setUom(String.valueOf(uom.getSelectedItem()));
                            db.addItem(new 

Model(Integer.parseInt(b.get("id").toString()), list.get(i).getitemId(), list.get(i).getQuantity(),list.get(i).getUom(),list.get(i).getAmt(),list.get(i).getTamount(),currentDateandTime));


                        }
                    }
                }
                });
                alert.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                         dialog.cancel(); 
                     }
                 });
                alert.show();
        }
     });

} 




private List<Model> getModel() {
    Intent i=getIntent();
    final Bundle b = i.getExtras();
    SqliteHelper db = new SqliteHelper(this);
    list = db.getProduct(b.get("itemname").toString());
    return list;
}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model>  {

    private final List<Model> list;


    String adapter;
    private final Activity context;
    private final int id;
    int listPosition;
    public MyAdapter(Activity context, List<Model> list, int id){
        super(context, R.layout.userproduct, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
        this.id = id;
    }


    class ViewHolder{
        protected TextView text;
        EditText quantity;
        protected TextView amount;
        TextView ext;
        Spinner uom;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        listPosition = position;
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.userproduct, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
            viewHolder.text.setFocusable(true);
            viewHolder.quantity = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inputQty);
            viewHolder.amount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inputAmt);
            viewHolder.uom = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inputUom);
            viewHolder.ext = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inputTamt);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        SqliteHelper db = new SqliteHelper(context);
        viewHolder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        viewHolder.quantity.setId(position);
        viewHolder.amount.setText(String.valueOf(list.get(position).getAmt()));
        viewHolder.amount.setId(position);
        viewHolder.ext.setId(position);
        viewHolder.uom.setId(position);
        viewHolder.text.setId(position);
        String data = db.getAllDetails(id, list.get(position).getitemId());
        String data2 = db.getExt(id,list.get(position).getitemId());

        if(data==null)
        {
            viewHolder.quantity.setText(list.get(position).quantity);
        }
        else{
            viewHolder.quantity.setText(data);
        }
        if(data2==null)
        {
            viewHolder.ext.setText(String.valueOf(list.get(position).ext));
        }
        else{
            viewHolder.ext.setText(data2);
        }
        viewHolder.quantity.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus){
                    list.get(position).quantity = ((EditText) v).getText().toString();

                }
            }
        });

        viewHolder.ext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus){
                    list.get(position).ext = (float) Integer.parseInt((((TextView) v).getText().toString()));

                }
            }
        });

        List<Model> uomlist = (List<Model>) db.selectUom(list.get(position).getitemId());
        List<String> myuom = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int j=0;j<uomlist.size();j++){
            myuom.add(uomlist.get(j).getUom());
        }


        ArrayAdapter<String> uomadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,myuom);
        uomadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        viewHolder.uom.setAdapter(uomadapter);

        return convertView;

    }
}
```